# Batch insert or update through Doctrine DBAL Query Builder

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

How can i do batch insert or update functionality through Doctrine DBAL Query  Builder.

```
$qb = $queryBuilder->values(
        array(
            "name" => 'test'
            "email" => 'test@gmail.com'
        )
    )
    ->insert('test')
    ->execute();
```

Will it supports like this

```
$qb = $queryBuilder->values(
            array(
                "name" => array('test', 'test2')
                "email" => array('test@gmail.com','test2@gmail.com')
            )
        )
        ->insert('test')
        ->execute();
```

Comment: There is a [chapter](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/batch-processing.html) in Doctrine's documentation about this. You should take a look.

Comment: @Artamiel This is ORM package, what if we only use the DBAL package?

Comment: @gskema Well, then I suppose you would have to take care of it by yourself since the 1 one I linked is all about `EntityManager` advantages. Writing an `insert` query with multiple values separated by a comma is one way to go. That way you can for instance execute your query once per 100 or 500 iterations of your values. I use this approach for a crawler module where no ORM is required.

Comment: I'm using DBAL, I actually found out that viable method to do a bulk update/insert is doing transactios, because they are grouped together before being executed. Also, if you're using MySQL you may opt for `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` to save data regardless if it exists of not

Answer (score 4):

There is an [unmerged pullrequest from some time ago, that adds this](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/pull/682). You can try to duplicate some of this functionality in your code.

In other words - no, it's not possible to do bulk insert using DBAL.